# Previous correct answer instead of creating a new one

Tags: privategpt

I am using PrivateGPT to chat with a PDF document. I ask a question and get an answer. If I am okay with the answer, and the same question is asked again, I want the previous answer instead of creating a new one. How can I handle this? Are there any options available?

settings-local.yaml

```
llm:

mode: llamacpp


max_new_tokens: 512

context_window: 3900

tokenizer: mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2

llamacpp:

prompt_style: "mistral"

llm_hf_repo_id: TheBloke/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2-GGUF

llm_hf_model_file: mistral-7b-instruct-v0.2.Q4_K_M.gguf

embedding:

mode: huggingface

huggingface:

embedding_hf_model_name: BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5

vectorstore:

database: qdrant

qdrant:

path: local_data/private_gpt/qdrant
```